# Change image with javascript onload

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change my image using Javascript. From using other topics, I got it almost all working; however, the gif animation isn't 'animating'. I believe this is because the JS is in some kind of infinite loop meaning the image is constantly loading; and therefore, the animation doesn't play.

Thanks for any help!

Douglas

**HTML CODE:**

```
<img id="mainImage" onload="changeImage()" src="images/ios_full.gif">
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
var isMobile = {
    android: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
    },
    ios: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
    },
    othermobile: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Blackberry|Opera Mini|IEMobile/i);
    },
};

function changeImage() {
    var image = document.getElementById('mainImage');
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var h = window.innerHeight;
    if ((isMobile.android()) && (w < 500 || h < 500)) {
        image.src = "images/android_short.gif";
    } else if (isMobile.android()) {
        image.src = "images/android_full.gif";
    } else if ((isMobile.ios()) && (w < 500 || h < 500)) {
        image.src = "images/ios_short.gif";
    } else if (isMobile.ios()) {
        image.src = "images/ios_full.gif";
    } else if (isMobile.othermobile()) {
        image.src = "images/other.gif";
    } else if (w < 800 || h < 500) {
        image.src = "images/ios_short.gif";
    } else {
        image.src = "images/ios_full.gif";
    }
}
```

Comment: you are correct, the onload is firing every time you set the `image.src` either use a global variable, or a data attrribute on the image tag, as a flag to check if you've done the onload already, or change your code to trigger the onload when the document loads, not when the image loads

Comment: Or, if you are using jQuery you could use the one binding to just have the event fire once.

Comment: Thanks Jaromanda X & user92454! Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be simply to kill the function (reassign it to an empty function) after it's done the first time since you won't be using it again anyway:

```
function changeImage() {
    var image = document.getElementById('mainImage');
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var h = window.innerHeight;
    if ((isMobile.android()) && (w < 500 || h < 500)) {
        image.src = "images/android_short.gif";
    } else if (isMobile.android()) {
        image.src = "images/android_full.gif";
    } else if ((isMobile.ios()) && (w < 500 || h < 500)) {
        image.src = "images/ios_short.gif";
    } else if (isMobile.ios()) {
        image.src = "images/ios_full.gif";
    } else if (isMobile.othermobile()) {
        image.src = "images/other.gif";
    } else if (w < 800 || h < 500) {
        image.src = "images/ios_short.gif";
    } else {
        image.src = "images/ios_full.gif";
    }
    changeImage = function(){}   // just this line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With HTML 5 you can do like this:

```
function changeImage() {
    var image = document.getElementById('mainImage');
    if(image.dataset.changed). {
        return;
    }
    image.dataset.changed = true;

    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var h = window.innerHeight;
    if ((isMobile.android()) && (w < 500 || h < 500)) {
        image.src = "images/android_short.gif";
    } else if (isMobile.android()) {
        image.src = "images/android_full.gif";
    } else if ((isMobile.ios()) && (w < 500 || h < 500)) {
        image.src = "images/ios_short.gif";
    } else if (isMobile.ios()) {
        image.src = "images/ios_full.gif";
    } else if (isMobile.othermobile()) {
        image.src = "images/other.gif";
    } else if (w < 800 || h < 500) {
        image.src = "images/ios_short.gif";
    } else {
        image.src = "images/ios_full.gif";
    }
     
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Best and easy way to Change image with javascript onload
Javascript change img src on load

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery('#logo img').attr('src','https://image-URL');
});

</script>
```